# Transform any devices into beacons : wifi + bluetooth (datzing like app)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, bluetooth, wifi, beacon

I'm actually working for a startup I'm building with two other founders. On the side I would like to develop a quick prototype to be able to deepdive into a subject I can use on my project : beacons.

Here is what I want to achieve : I want to be able to use a device as an emitter (using bluetooth, BLE, or wifi) and the other one to be able to know when it enters the first one range. I need that to be able to do indoor localization (just a check in system, not to know exactly where people are in that specific location).

I'm used to code mobile application with Ionic and I'm more a Javascript developer. I saw that there is already something which fit to my needs : Dazting which transform every device mobile as "a beacon" with either bluetooth or Wifi. Problem, I want to do it on my own but to be honest I don't really now how they manage to do that with Wifi. I know that there are some libraries to emit with BLE but what about bluetooth ?

Does it mean I'll have to code it with native code ?

This is what I want to achieve :

- Coding an hybrid app (will loose less time and one app for every
  platform)
- Transforming the mobile device into an emitter : with bluetooth or
  wifi
- Be able to know the distance between a device which will emit and a
  one that will receive the signal
- I don't want to go with beacons : I'm not going to use macro-location and buying beacons for my project at the start is not something we would like to do.

Any ideas or suggestions on how did Datzing manage to reach that goal ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datzing relies on emission of Bluetooth Classic, Bluetooth LE and WiFi packets from a mobile device that is made discoverable, either programmatically or through manual selection in settings.  The unique MAC address or SSID of the device can then be used to tie the detected transmission to a registered "Beacon" on the Datzing system.  Basically it just registers the unique identifier associated with a Bluetooth or WiFi transmission with the Datzing servers so they can have meaning.

Using this technology to transmit on an iOS device is severely limited due to operating system restrictions.  Users essentially have to manually go to settings screens to start the emissions.  Android devices are much more flexible if you have a native app granted the proper permissions.

On the detection side, iOS is also much more limited than Android due to the operating system blocking access to raw MAC addresses of bluetooth devices and preventing detecting SSIDs of WiFi access points unless the network is connected.  As of Android 6.0, access to the raw MAC address is also restricted, making such a system work less well with Bluetooth on newer Android devices.

On both platforms, iOS and Android, the ability to use these techniques to the extent they are allowed by the operating system are possible with native code.  Doing so with Ionic or Cordova would require cobbling together a number of plugins (if they even exist) to bridge to the native features to access WiFi SSIDs and do Bluetooth discovery and scanning.  This is unlikely to be a quick protoype.

Word of caution:  It is always a good idea to try out a system like Datzing before trying to reproduce it yourself, as limitations often cause technologies not to live up to the claims of the marketing materials.